# Exhibition preparation - What is an artist biography for someone in the early stage?

Tags: painting

I have done few exhibitions few years ago, then I stopped and stayed away from the art scene for a while.

I have new work that I would like to submit to galleries but they are asking for an artist biography.

What should it include?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it not about applied arts and crafts but more the business side of professional artists which is not currently the sites focus. You are welcome to bring this up in [meta] for continued discussion if this does get closed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer this without knowing the specifics. But what I can say is that a gallery will look for some kind of narrative that ties your experience as an artist together. Generally you should include your most recent/most prestigious shows from the past, and then draw a connection between your former work and your current work using the time you spent not exhibiting.

Is there something you studied during the time you weren't showing work that has influenced your current work? Don't dwell on it, but do mention it. I find that art lovers have a positive view of artists with interests outside of the arts, so I'm sure you'll be able to massage some nice sounding narrative out of whatever you were doing.

Comment: During the time I wasn't doing any exhibition, i was reading books. My work is mostly inspired from literature and it interprets some books.

Comment: Find a theme (up to two themes, no more) that connects the literature you were reading together and say you were studying that. Since your new work is in fact related to the reading you did, it sounds like you won't have too much trouble making your time off come across as purposeful. Good luck!